# window.getComputedStyle does not return borderRadius on MS Edge and IE

Tags: javascript

I have an element which has border-radius.

`window.getComputedStyle(my_element_with_border_radius, null).borderRadius` returns nothing on MS Edge and IE.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: how about `window.getComputedStyle(my_element_with_border_radius).getPropertyValue("border-radius")` ?

Comment: @AminJafari nope, the same result.

Comment: The `border-radius` property is a composite property, the true properties set with it are `border-top-left-radius`, `border-top-right-radius`, `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`. Looks like you've to retrieve these values (or one of them) instead.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks, I have noticed. I'm trying to extract the border radius out of one those